# ¿Puedo relacionar una clave foránea de un atributo de una tabla con otra clave foránea de un atributo de otra tabla?

Tags: base-de-datos

Deseo saber si se puede relacionar dos claves foraneas puesto que solo he visto clave primaria con una foranea entonces deseria saber si se puede primaria con foranea

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la necesidad a cubrir para hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, la respuesta seria NI.

Si las dos son claves foraneas, definitivamente son claves principales de una tabla.

La idea de nombrar a algo como clave foranea o primaria, es solo una idea para identificar, si esa clave en realidad significa que son datos (relacionados) de otra tabla, o si es una clave propia que identifica inequivocamente a un registro de la propia tabla.

Teoricamente, ninguna BD te va a dejar relacionar una clave foranea con otra clave foranea. Sin embargo, puede que esa clave primaria este en mas de una tabla como clave foranea.

Entonces, nada te impediria hacer un query que las relacione.

Digamos que tenemos la tabla pais.. con su respectiva clave primaria

```
Pais
CodPais PK int 
Pais varchar
```

y tenemos las tablas

```
Personas
CodPersona PK int
Nombre varchar
CodPais FK -> Pais

Banderas
CodBandera PK int
Color varchar
CodPais FK -> Pais
```

Nada impediria unir las tablas personas y banderas, aunque no tenga ningun sentido. pero podriamos mostrar para cada persona, todos los colores de banderas que tienen si estan en el mismo pais.

Answer (score 0):

Según las reglas de integridad referencial no, puesto que a cada clave foránea le debe corresponder una única clave primaria.
Lo puede consultar [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integridad_referencial).

En cuanto al modelo que expone gbianchi, estaría mal planteado ya que la relación en ese caso debería ser según las reglas de normalización:

```
País -> Bandera -> Persona
```

De esa forma podrías unir las tablas desde País hasta persona y viceversa, exponiendo los colores como el explica en el ejemplo. A la vez en programación, y en un modelo orientado a objetos, podrías acceder desde el Modelo País al objeto Persona relacionado y viceversa.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda sobre porque siempre ves una foreign key que se relaciona con una primary key únicamente y no una foreign key que se relaciones con otra foreign key, pues esto rompería con la integridad referencial y produciría resultados ambiguos en lugar de resultados únicos y determinados como se esperaría.

Saludos.

Comment: Ojo, yo nunca explique el transfondo de mi ejemplo. Vos estas suponiendo reglas de negocios que no tienen porque ser correctas. Yo solo demostre que se puede hacer una query asi, lo que no significa que sirva para algo.

Comment: Y si la relación es de 1 a 1? Se cumpliría que la clave foránea se corresponde unicamente a sí misma.  en una relación 1 a 1 se puede usar la clave primaria del padre como clave primaria y foranea de la tabla del hijo?